# SQLite INSERT via Python

Tags: python, sqlite, insert

I have a table with `55` columns with `CDR` data.

The task is to update the table with new values from `.tsv(.csv)` file. The simple way is to put '`?`' `55` times into SQL statement

`INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES(?, ? ...., (rows))`.

Could it be done more elegantly?

Comment: "a table with 55 columns". This sounds like bad design.

Comment: It's billing CDR's. I have no idea how it could be splited

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the beholder, but you could generate your command string using `'?,' * 55`

Comment: cdarke 
Could you explain in detail?

Comment: @heavy_drinker Try entering `'?,' * 55` at the Python prompt. If you want to avoid snipping of the last comma, use `','.join(['?'] * 55)`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). It is an ORM Toolkit for all variants of SQL. I never wright raw SQL into my code. It quickly becomes a mess and frustrating to work with.